# Partial Derivatives and defining a function.

Tags: partial-derivative

Define

> f(x,y) = x+2y and w = x+y.

What is $\frac{df}{dw}$? Does it make sense to define the partial derivative of a function `f` with respect to an arbitrary function `w`(not just `x` or `y`)? If so, what does this definition give for the specific example $f(x,y) = x+2y$ and $w = x+y$?

Comment: Are you asking because you saw this somewhere? If so, perhaps you could say a bit more about the context.

Comment: Nope, this is just a lone question. Everything that's written I have included here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a question like this it's important to be clear on which variables are independent, and which depend on the others. The most natural interpretation of your question is that $x$ and $y$ are independent variables, and $f$ and $w$ are both functions of $x$ and $y$. In this case $\frac{df}{dw}$ doesn't make sense.

To see why, recall that the notation $\frac{dp}{dq}$ represents the change in $p$ over the change in $q$. If $p(q)$ is a function of a single independent variable $q$, and $q_1$ and $q_2$ are close together, then
$$
  \frac{p(q_1)-p(q_2)}{q_1-q_2}\approx\left.\frac{dp}{dq}\right|_{q_1}.
$$
Now consider the functions $f$ and $w$ depending on two independent variables $x$ and $y$. Consider the points $(x_1,y_1)=(0,0)$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(1,0)$. The change in $f$ over the change in $w$ is
$$
  \frac{f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)}{w(x_1,y_1)-w(x_2,y_2)}
    =\frac{0-1}{0-1}=1.
$$
On the other hand, consider $(x_3,y_3)=(0,1)$. Then
$$
  \frac{f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_3,y_3)}{w(x_1,y_1)-w(x_3,y_3)}
    =\frac{0-2}{0-1}=2.
$$
So there is no single value that makes sense for $\frac{df}{dw}$ at $(0,0)$. (you might worry that the points just aren't close enough together, but in fact you can make them as close as you want and get the same numbers).

---

Another possible interpretation is that $w$ is part of a change of variables, such as $(w,z)=(x+y,x-y)$. In this case we can also express $(x,y)$ in terms of $(w,z)$, namely $(x,y)=(\frac{w+z}2,\frac{w-z}2)$. Thus both pairs $(x,y)$ and $(w,z)$ can act as a pair of independent variables; we can express $f$ in terms of either:
$$
  f=x+2y=\frac32w-\frac12z.
$$
It does make sense to compute the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $w$:
$$
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial w}=\frac32.
$$
This means that if $w_1,\,w_2$ are close and $z_0$ is fixed,
$$
  \frac{f(w_1,z_0)-f(w_2,z_0)}{w_1-w_2}\approx\frac32.
$$
Note that we are using the same value $z_0$ for both points here; the partial derivative gives the rate of change with respect to $w$ **while $z$ is fixed**. This also means that we need to know the variable $z$ that is paired with $w$ to form independent variables. I could equally well do a change of variables $(w,v)=(x+y,2y)$, and this would give a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not meaningful unless you specify a coordinate system $(w,z)$ where $w$ is one of the coordinates. When computing $\partial f/\partial w$, you should first express $f$ in terms of $w$ and $z$, and then hold the other variable $z$ constant when you differentiate, so the result depends on what $z$ is.

Sometimes the notation
$$\left. \frac{\partial f}{\partial w} \right|_z$$
is used, to emphasize this.

Answer (score -2):

$\dfrac{df}{dw} = \dfrac{df}{dx}\cdot \dfrac{dx}{dw} + \dfrac{df}{dy}\cdot \dfrac{dy}{dw}= \dfrac{\dfrac{df}{dx}}{\dfrac{dw}{dx}}+\dfrac{\dfrac{df}{dy}}{\dfrac{dw}{dy}}=\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{2}{1}=3.$

Comment: This calculation gives different answers after a change of variables (eg (a,b)=(x+y,x-y)), so I don't think it's meaningful. Are you taking w to be an independent variable which x and y both depend on?